# How to handle API that returns plain text, one word per line, in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rest

I understand how to make REST requests and handle the returning JSON data, but now I need to work with an API that returns data as plain text, one word per line.

Assuming I can just make a standard GET request, how do I parse the plain text response into something I can use—an array of strings?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you receive the string as UTF8 encoded `Data`.

Create the string from the data and separate the paragraphs by the `newlines` `CharacterSet` which considers many different newline separators.

```
let paragraphs = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the piece I was missing.